# DocuSign required field if trigger text field is not blank?

Tags: docusignapi

We are trying to make a field conditionally required base on if the trigger text field is not empty. All we can find is examples for checkbox, radio button, etc.... but not for a text field.

We cannot figure out how to set the property on the child text tab ConditionalParentValue = "Any Value"

How would we set this?

Answer (score 2):

This is what we finally found and it worked

conditionalParentValue = "##ANY##"